# Loops and logic statements

Tags: java, loops, boolean-logic

I have this program needed for class and the way they ask me to complete it is confusing me as i am unable to output the proper answer. what is needed is a series of inputs that contain a series of 'x''s 'X''s and 'r''s which in turn outputs a sound. if the input contains a character that is not an 'x' 'X' or an 'r' it must output something along the lines of "please enter a valid input." For the most part i had everything down but i am unable to figure out a way to properly display the invalid input string.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class String2Beat { //main class
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("To play a drum song please enter a series of x's and r's."); 
    System.out.println("Use an Uppercase X for the base drum, "); 
    System.out.println("Use a Lowercase x for the snare drum, "); 
    System.out.println("Or use a Uppercase R for a rest:"); 
    String drums = scan.nextLine(); 

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        for (int i = 0; i < drums.length(); i++){
            if (drums.charAt(i) != 'x' && drums.charAt(i) != 'X' && drums.charAt(i) != 'r'){
                System.out.println("not a valid string input");
            }
            else {
                if (drums.charAt(i) == 'X'){
                    System.out.println("Now playing a Bass Drum. " + drums.charAt(i)); 
                    playBass(); 
                }
                else if(drums.charAt(i) == 'x'){
                    System.out.println("Now playing a Snare Drum. " + drums.charAt(i)); 
                    playSnare(); 
                }
                else if(drums.charAt(i) == 'r'){
                    System.out.println("Now playing a Rest. " + drums.charAt(i)); 
                    playRest(); 
                }
            }

        }

    }

    scan.close();
}
```

Comment: This is Java, not JavaScript.  `System.out` does not a good Javascript program make.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is figure out if the String contains an invalid input before you play the sounds. Your program should probably look something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class String2Beat { //main class
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("To play a drum song please enter a series of x's and r's."); 
    System.out.println("Use an Uppercase X for the base drum, "); 
    System.out.println("Use a Lowercase x for the snare drum, "); 
    System.out.println("Or use a Uppercase R for a rest:"); 
    String drums = scan.nextLine(); 

    boolean test = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < drums.length(); i++)
    {
        if (drums.charAt(i) != 'X' || drums.charAt(i) != 'x' || drums.charAt(i) != 'R')
            test = true;
    }

    if (!test)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < drums.length(); i++)
            {
                    if (drums.charAt(i) == 'X')
                    {
                        System.out.println("Now playing a Bass Drum. " + drums.charAt(i)); 
                        playBass(); 
                    }
                    else if(drums.charAt(i) == 'x')
                    {
                        System.out.println("Now playing a Snare Drum. " + drums.charAt(i)); 
                        playSnare(); 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Now playing a Rest. " + drums.charAt(i)); 
                        playRest(); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("not a valid string input");
    }

    scan.close();
}
```